# In Angular 1.4, within a controller, can I insert "events" to execute before an $http request, and after a success/error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Angular UI application that needs to make a lot of data requests.  As is typical, I need a responsive UI, even when the APIs I'm calling are not so fast at returning results.  This means I need to put the application in a "*Loading...*" state quite often.

I can do this by setting a loading flag that the Angular UI keys off of as the state changes, but what this looks like is something like this:

```
$scope.requestFooData = function() {

   var parameters = $scope.BuildFooParams();

   //'loadingData' is a state variable that the UI uses 
   //for disabling regions, or showing spinners where 
   //and when applicable.
   $scope.loadingData = true;
   $http.get("API/getFoo" + parameters)
       .success(function(data) {
           //Handle data
           $scope.loadingData = false;
       })
       .error(function() {
           //Address the error
           $scope.loadingData = false;
       });
}
```

This works, but it's at least three lines of code I have to remember to integrate within each request. Not only that, but I may need to bury some API calls within subsequent success API calls, cascading API requests.  In that case, it'd be nice to wire in a semaphore that can determine when to properly set the loading state.  That logic gets a little more complex and convoluted under this approach.

Is there a way that on initialization of my controllers I can inject an  method that fires when any web request is made (GET/POST/etc.) and once the results come back, it fires off another event for  state clean up?

Comment: What is connection between "Angular 4" in the header and the code example on AngularJS?

Comment: @katzz0 Only that I'm not an "Angular guy" and I know this old project is using Angular 4. If there are limitations to this versions of Angular (1.4.3), I am not at liberty to update the application.  But as I pointed out, I only work in Angular when I need to and I'm not up to date on the nuanced changes within the specific versions. I just want to be sure that any given solution works for our use case.

Answer (score 1):

The reset of the spinner flag can be put in a `.finally` block:

```
$scope.loadingData = true;
$http.get("API/getFoo" + parameters)
  .then(function(response) {
    var data = response.data;
    //Handle data
    ̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶l̶o̶a̶d̶i̶n̶g̶D̶a̶t̶a̶ ̶=̶ ̶f̶a̶l̶s̶e̶;̶
}).catch(function(response) {
    //Address the error
    ̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶l̶o̶a̶d̶i̶n̶g̶D̶a̶t̶a̶ ̶=̶ ̶f̶a̶l̶s̶e̶;̶ 
}).finally(function() {
    $scope.loadingData = false;
});
```

The `.finally` block allows you to observe either the fulfillment or rejection of a promise, but to do so without modifying the final value. This is useful to release resources or do some clean-up that needs to be done whether the promise was rejected or resolved.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $q Service API Reference - The Promise API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api)

Answer (score 0):

You should use HttpInterceptor. 
For example, make some AppStateService with busy boolean property, bind some markup to it and then create httpintercepter which will set this property in accdoring to request state.

Comment: I think this the answer I need.  Unfortunately, the Angular documentation does not give an example.  If you can post a simplistic example and I can verify this will work with my need outlined above, I'll give you the answer mark.  Thank you.

Comment: https://thinkster.io/interceptors, here is an example of an interceptor being used. 
As far as IE11 compatibility is concerned, I think it does support IE11. This their official docs page regarding it: https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.14/docs/guide/ie

Answer (score 0):

You can use interceptors also for Angular.js 1.4 check documentation [there](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.14/docs/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors). The is idea is the same as described by Iga Uga - create a service capture the state of http requests. I can use this service everywhere in the app then to display a loader icon while na http request is on going or do something else.

BTW: Older angular versions are named **angular.js** and newer versions starting with Angular 2 are just **Angular**.